# Python: Why am I getting ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I have read and tried different things, but it is not working.

```
def product():

    y, x= raw_input('Please enter two numbers: ')
    times = float(x) * int(y)
    print 'product is', times
product()
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a single string.  to unpack arguments as you're doing, it would need to return 2 things.

You could do something like this:

```
y, x = raw_input('Please enter two numbers (separated by whitespace): ').split(None,1)
```

Note that this is still a little fragile because the user could input a string like "2 1 3".  The unpacking would work without an exception, but it would choke when trying to convert "1 3" to an integer.  The most robust way to do these things is via a `try/except` block.  Here's how I would do it.

```
while True: #try to get 2 numbers forever.
   try:
      y, x = raw_input("2 numbers please (integer, float): ").split()
      y = int(y)
      x = float(x)
      break  #got 2 numbers, we can stop trying and do something useful with them.
   except ValueError:
      print "Oops, that wasn't an integer followed by a float.  Try again"
```

Comment: Although a more flexible solution would be to just grab the string `string = raw_input('...')` and then split and parse it out in a `try:... except:...` block, raising the error to the user. It also makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you much! This one works very well too. thank you so much i have learnt a lot here. thanks to you all once again.

Answer (score 0):

@mgilson's answer is correct; except if someone enters three numbers you'll get the same `ValueError` exception.

So, this alternate version catches that:

```
numbers = raw_input('Please enter only two numbers separated by a space: ').split()
if len(numbers) > 2:
   print 'Sorry, you must enter only two numbers!'
else:
   x,y = numbers
```

Comment: Why not just `try: x,y = raw_input().split(); except ValueError: print 'Sorry ...'` ?

Comment: For readability since OP seems to be new; try/except might confuse things.